# Background switch based on URL query

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

So I am looking to swap out background images based on a URL, which in this case will be based on a user's destination. I have a lot of background images and the correct background needs to be shown based on the url string. For example, if the URL is this:

http://fakeUrl.net?dest=ord

there is a background image that is associated with the query 'ord'.

Since I have a lot of stationcodes (i.e., 'ord', 'lax', etc.) and a lot of images, I want to create a function where it shows the correct image based on the stationcode.

I have images simply named: 'dest-a', 'dest-b', and so on. This is what I have so far (assume the if/else statement works - I am not adding that code in for this example):

```
var stationCodes = /abq|abr|aby|ack|aex|ags|alb|anc|apn|atl|atw|aus|avl| ......
var bgPath = 'static/4.0/img/backgrounds/';
    var bgImgs = {
        //SLC Region
            bzn: 'dest-a',
            cos: 'dest-a',
            den: 'dest-a',
            slc: 'dest-a',
        //Desert Pacific NW Region
            abq: 'dest-b'
        };

            var bgSwap = bgPath + bgImgs[DEST] + '.jpg';

            if(DEVICE !== 'mobile'){
                if( stationCodes.test(DEST)) {
                    $('#container-mainContent').css('background-image', 'url('+ bgSwap +')');
                }
                else {
                    $('#container-mainContent').css('background-image', 'url('+ bgPath + 'dest-p.jpg)');
                }
        }
```

I want to get rid of the 'var bgImgs' method of adding the station code individually and then adding the appropriate background image based on the destination because it will become very redundant. How can I create a function where it will swap the background image correctly based on the URL query which has the stationcode?

Answer (score 0):

```
function setBackgroundImage (stationCode) {

    var path = "static/4.0/img/backgrounds/";
    var image = null;

    switch (stationCode) {
        case "bzn":
        case "cos":
        case "den":
        case "slc":
            image = "dest-a.jpg";
            break;
        case "abq":
            image = "dest-b.jpg";
            break;

        /* More cases here... */

        default:
            image = "dest-p.jpg";
            break;
    }

    var backgroundString = "url(" + path + image + ")";
    document.getElementById("container-mainContent").style.backgroundImage = backgroundString;
}
```